# How can I compare C-style strings?

Tags: c++, palindrome

The for loop reverses original string 's' and stores it in 'temp.'Temp is printed correctly.  After which, s and temp are compared, but the result always shows NO. :(

```
#include<cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char s[100], temp[100];
        cin >> s;
        cout << strlen(s);
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            temp[i]=s[strlen(s)-i];
        }
        cout << "temp is" << temp;
        if(temp==s)
        {
            cout << "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NO";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You never terminate the string in `temp` properly, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And if you're programming in C++, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) instead.

Comment: `std::string s; cin >> s; if ( s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend() ) cout << "YES"; else cout << "NO";`  That is your entire program using C++.

Comment: does not the first round of the loop add '\0' to temp? This would essentially create an empty string with all the other parts of the loop being useless but I wonder why there is an output that OP describes

Comment: @IceFire Yes it does, it's probably `for (int i = 1;` in his real code. I'll leave that little rest of debugging to him.

Comment: Btw, had you enabled more warnings, the compiler may have told you what's wrong. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fc943ab77d09b01

Comment: Good test case though, keep it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strcmp` instead of `==` because the latter is merely a pointer comparison. Also, '\0' has to be used to end your string. And your current code would actually create an empty string because your string at position `strlen(s)` contains '\0'.

Then again, you should not work with char arrays in C++ on your own, rather use `std::string` as already pointed out in comments.

Comment: there are multiple errors in the code, comparing `char[]` using operator  `==` is not the only one. . .

Comment: good point, I added some more text